# how to add personal data augmentation?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection

my code looks like this:

```
 with strategy.scope():
        model_lib_v2.train_loop(
            pipeline_config_path=helper.pipeline_config_path,
            model_dir=model_dir,
            use_tpu=False,
            checkpoint_every_n=FLAGS.checkpoint_every_n,
            record_summaries=FLAGS.record_summaries)
```

all data augmentation is added in the config file, which looks like this:

`data_augmentation_options { random_distort_color { } }`
so, how can I define a new augmentation function?

My config file is just the same as in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_shared_box_predictor_640x640_coco14_sync.config

And now, I want to define a new data augmentation function. How can I do it? Is there any tutorial? The total tensorflow code is too complex for me to find where to add the function.